# Renomear gitignore.txt para .gitignore

Tags: windows

Criei um arquivo gitignore no Windows, para que alguns arquivos desnecessários, não sejam upados para o o GitHub. Porém, este arquivo está com a extensão ".txt" (`gitignore.txt`). Quero deixá-lo somente como `.gitignore`.

Como posso fazer isto ? Existe alguma possibilidade de renomeá-lo pela linha de comando?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Através do explorer não é possível renomear um arquivo de forma a que tenha apenas extensão, é considerado como não tendo nome, o que não é permitido.

A solução passa por abrir uma janela de comando e utilizar o comando `rename`:

- No explorer abra a pasta onde está o arquivo.
- Com a tecla <kbd>shift</kbd> pressionada clique com o botão do lado direito do rato uma zona vazia da pasta.
- No menu apresentado escolha a opção "Abrir janela de comando aqui"
- Na janela que abriu escreva o comando `rename gitignore.txt .gitignore`
- Tecle <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: Obrigado conseguir resolver,.

Comment: Não sei se reparou mas a resposta que aceitou não está completamente correcta: Via explorer é possível apagar a extensão mas não é possível colocar o `.` à esquerda do nome.

Comment: marquei enganado , desculpa.

Comment: Tambem achei um comando aqui no propio terminal do git este:

mv .gitigonre.txt .gitignore

Answer (score 1):

Na linha de comando digite:

```
ren .gitignore.txt .gitignore
```

Para acessar a linha de comando a partir da pasta atual vá na barra de endereços e digite `cmd`.

Via explorer apenas pressione `F2` e remova a extensão.

Comment: Obrigado conseguir resolver,.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode abrir o seu arquivo no bloco de notas e utilizar o salvar como. Na janela de salvar como selecione `tipo de arquivo` como `todos(*)` e remova o .txt da extensão.

Ou pela linha de comando vá até a pasta do seu arquivo e utilize:

```
rename .gitignore.txt .gitignore
```

Comment: Obrigado conseguir resolver,.